# Supportmapfragment Map not showing on published App ( Fine while testing on device in Eclipse)

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

Testing on an actual device (Galaxy y api10) in Eclipse, the Google Map works fine.
The published App installed on the same device shows a blank grey rectangle instead of the map.

Any suggestions on what could have gone wrong?

Part of the manifest:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.xxxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.xxxxx.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
 The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Java

```
FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            SupportMapFragment supportmapfragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragment;
            map = supportmapfragment.getMap();
```

Comment: Did you updated the manifest to point to the new key(and not the debug key most likely) tied to the certificate with which you signed the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you update the API key? 
Remember the API key is created from your keystore. If your map works in debug mode (from eclipse so), it's because you created the key with the debug.keystore.

Now your app is published under a new keystore, you have to create a new API key with your new keystore.